# Select to include NULL or empty in the result

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I would like to do a select below even result is `NULL`.

Query is below

```
SELECT id, result
FROM  `fq_account_extend_result` 
WHERE id_extend =5
AND (
id =1
OR id =2
OR id =3
OR id =4
)
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Result below:

```
id  result
1   testtest
2   asdasd
3   bill
```

I would like to include `id_extend = 4`, even the result is empty

```
id  result
1   testtest
2   asdasd
3   bill
4
```

Comment: i don't see any question here ...

Comment: @ChristianMark got it.

Comment: which null field are talking about? `id_extend` or `result`?

Comment: @hims056 if the result is empty

Comment: @bluebill1049 - Please show the sample data for your expected result.

Comment: yes. check my answer and comment the result

Comment: @ChristianMark thx christian i think you nailed although my question is not explained very well. Thanks

Comment: @bluebill1049: Actually it's a wildcard. If you add data, or more info, I can provide you the SQLFiddle. You can mark it as answer tho.

Comment: Yes about to mark yours as answer 2 mins to go

Comment: If your `WHERE` condition is `WHERE id_extend IN(1,2,3,4)` and `result` field is `NULL` for `id_extend=4` it [will show that raw](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af501d/1) as well.

Comment: @hims056 wow that's even cleaner thanks i will update my sql statement

Comment: @bluebill1049 Why you can't show us sample data? `hims056` has right so I think you have to provide more information

Comment: @Parado sorry i should include the data just forgot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
   SELECT id_extend, result
    FROM  fq_account_extend_result
    WHERE id =5 AND
    id_extend IN(1,2,3,4)
    OR result is null
    ORDER BY id ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id_extend, result
```

FROM  `fq_account_extend_result`
WHERE id =5
AND id_extend IN (1,2,3,4)
ORDER BY id ASC